# Create new variable with "Yes/No" depending on if other variables have "Yes". Mutate?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a database with information:

```
Patient_number | Arterial_thrombosis | Venous_thrombosis |
1                Yes                   No         
2                No                    Yes
```

I wish to create a new variable called "Any_thrombosis" that says "Yes" if either Arterial_thrombosis and/or Venous_thrombosis is equal to "Yes" and "No" if both say No.

I have tried this:

```
dataframe %>% mutate(Any_thrombosis = ifelse(Arterial_thrombosis == "Yes" | Venous_thrombosis == "Yes"), 'Yes', 'No')
```

But I get this error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Any_thrombosis`.
x argument "yes" is missing, with no default
i Input `Any_thrombosis` is `ifelse(Arterial_thrombosis == "Yes" | Venous_thrombosis == "Yes")`
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The closing bracket of `ifelse` is at wrong position.

Comment: @Duck Your logic is off.  If _any_ of the two columns be yes, then the result is yes.  You are assigning yes exclusively when _both_ columns are yes only.

Answer (score 0):

I would phrase your logic by checking for the positive case of both conditions being no first, and assigning no to the new column in this case.  Otherwise, if not true, then it means that at least one of the two columns is yes.

In base R:

```
dataframe$Any_thrombosis <-
    ifelse(dataframe$Arterial_thrombosis == "No" &
           dataframe$Venous_thrombosis == "No", "No", "Yes")
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer:

```
> transform(df, Any_thrombosis = ifelse((Arterial_thrombosis == 'Yes') | (Venous_thrombosis == 'Yes'), 'Yes','No'))
  Patient_number Arterial_thrombosis Venous_thrombosis Any_thrombosis
1              1                 Yes                No            Yes
2              2                  No               Yes            Yes
>
```